# Are C# struct parameters and locals aligned by default?

Tags: c#, simd, memory-alignment

Assume I have a struct defined like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16, Pack = 1)]
readonly struct Example {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float A;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public float B;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public float C;
    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public float D;
}
```

Are local and argument instances of `Example` guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned?

Specifically, I'm curious whether I can use `Unsafe.As` to re-interpret such a struct to a `Vector4`:

```
static void Test(Example e) {
    var vec4 = Unsafe.As<Example, Vector4>(ref e); // Is vec4 aligned?

    var e2 = new Example();
    vec4 = Unsafe.As<Example, Vector4>(ref e2); // Is vec4 aligned?
}
```

Comment: Why do you care about alignment of local arguments and instances here? As far as I understand you should care only about size and layout in case such reinterpret.

Comment: @GuruStron `Unsafe.As` is used here to reinterpret that struct as a `Vector4`

Comment: @harold yes, I understand that. Rules of alignment does of "instances" here should not matter here. Only the size and layout of the structs itself.

Comment: @GuruStron well, theoretically it matters. After all as the documentation says, "The caller is also responsible for ensuring that the resulting pointer is properly aligned for the referenced type". There is some question about what alignment `Vector4` requires to begin with, but certainly in general we have to care about the alignment of the instance that is being reinterpreted.

Comment: @harold maybe I misunderstand the _"Are local and argument instances of Example guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned?"_ question from OP then. I understand it to be about alignment of "instances" on stack of current method, which is not a factor for the following question about `Unsafe.As`.

Comment: It is a factor, producing an address that is not aligned as much as the target type requires is in general not correct (we usually get away with that on x64 anyway)

Comment: @harold _"ref e will point to the same address"_ should be _"the same data"_ i.e. "start" of the instance.

Comment: Given a `Vector4` anyway needs to be loaded into registers to do SIMD, why not just load the four variables manually using the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locals and arguments of struct types are not necessarily "overaligned" (ie aligned to anything more than would be required for scalar code). `Example` doesn't require an alignment of 16 so there was no specific motivation for the JIT compiler to ensure that it gets it, it may happen anyway of course, and I had to modify the source a bit to get an unaligned address (well, not 16-aligned, from a scalar point of view it's still sufficiently aligned).

Here's a screenshot of it actually not being 16-aligned in practice:

[image: Debugger showing an address of 000000D29C57E6F8]

In order to make this happen, I inserted another struct parameter before `e`, one with size 8.

The redundant moves are there because this happened in unoptimized mode (JIT optimization suppressed on module load, which is the default for debugging but it can be turned off to debug optimized code, which has its own issues).

However, clearly the load resulting from the `Unsafe.As` was an unaligned load (`vmovupd`, theoretically this is the instruction to load a vector of 2 doubles instead of 4 floats but that makes no actual difference), so no exception resulted from the misalignment. I could not find clear documentation on what kind of alignment is *officially* required to load a `Vector4` this way.